# Activating a window while retaining Z-order

Tags: winapi

I need to activate a window that is possibly behind other windows, but the window should remain behind - it shouldn't be brought to front.
Is there a way to do that? I've tried `SetWindowPos` with various parameters, but no success so far.

Basically, I need to close a non-active window (by posting `WM_SYSCOMMAND` with `SC_CLOSE`), but that window may show a confirmation dialog before closing. If the dialog is shown, it needs to be brought to front, otherwise the window should stay behind.

Comment: This makes little sense.  Sending WM_SYSCOMMAND doesn't require it to be in the foreground.  If it does move in the foreground then it isn't going to be there for long, you are closing it.  No point in not doing this consistently, SetForegroundWindow().  Beware that this may not work if the window belongs to another process, you may well get a blinking taskbar button instead.

Comment: _If it does move in the foreground then it isn't going to be there or long, you are closing it._

That's part of the problem: if I bring it to the foreground, and it doesn't show extra dialogs, it will "flash" - appear and disappear. This is not desirable.

Comment: Well, send WM_SYSCOMMAND and if it is still there after a second or two then bring it into the foreground?

Comment: That will work, but I prefer to avoid the delay if possible.